# How to remove string from ArrayList after show it in a label?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I have a label and ArrayList. ArrayList consists of strings from sqlite column.

When I press "1" on keyboard a random string from ArrayList should be applied to text in label and after that should be removed from ArrayList. 
The main goal is to not show strings from ArrayList twice when I always press "1"

**How can I do that?**

**Should I use another list from collections for that purpose?**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
@FXML private Label lb_randomCard;


mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
  switch (event.getCode()) {

    case DIGIT1:
      showRandomQuestionCat2();

      break;

  }
});
```

I've tried to do this, but random strings has been still appeared:

```
private void showRandomQuestionCat2() {

  Random rand = new Random();
  String randomString = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
  lb_randomCard.setText(randomString);
  list.remove(randomString);

 }
```

**EDIT:** 
I've tried to use Collections.shuffle but nothing happens.

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
    String randomString = list.get(index);
    lb_randomCard.setText(randomString);
    list.remove(index);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry guys for my stupidity! I pasted wrong code and my full method is:

```
private void showRandomQuestionCat2() {

    int n = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
      if (n < 70) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        String randomString = list.get(index);
        lb_randomCard.setText(list.get(index));
        index++;
        list.remove(index);

      } else if (n < 80) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index2 = rand.nextInt(listSentence.size());
        String randomString = listSentence.get(index2);
        lb_randomCard.setText(listSentence.get(index2));
        index2++;
        listSentence.remove(index2);

        }
    }
```

When I removed

```
int n = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

all random things goes correctly.

By creating this random thing at the beginning of the method I wanted to make chance 70%/30% to show strings from two arrays.

But now I don't know how to make the same with chance but without duplicates

**EDIT3:**

THis is the video that show how duplicate strings show:

[Video](https://mega.nz/#!bVcSnCBa!n3C5qLBLoHRNKPvm6Bb6QvEPmTOpxw3rukjbq7oGp44)

This is my full code with two arrays:

```
@FXML  private AnchorPane mainAnchor

@FXML  private Label lb_randomCard;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> listSentence = new ArrayList<>();

@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

//key commands
mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
  switch (event.getCode()) {

    case DIGIT1:
      generateChar();
      Collections.shuffle(list);
      Collections.shuffle(listSentence);
      showRandomQuestionCat2();
      showRandomCard();

  }
});

 }

//put all values from SQLite table category1 to ArryayList
private void getAllQuest() {


  try {
    Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getGetQuestions());
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
      list.add(rs.getString("question"));
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

  //put all values from SQLite table sentences to ArryayList
  private void getAllSentences() {

    try {
      Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
      pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getGetSentences());
      rs = pst.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
        listSentence.add(rs.getString("sentence"));
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

//set random string from both Arrays and remove after that
  private void showRandomQuestionCat2() {

    int n = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
      if (n < 70) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        String randomString = list.get(index);
        lb_randomCard.setText(list.get(index));
        index++;
        list.remove(index);

      } else if (n < 80) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index2 = rand.nextInt(listSentence.size());
        String randomString = listSentence.get(index2);
        lb_randomCard.setText(listSentence.get(index2));
        index2++;
        listSentence.remove(index2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the list have duplicate elements? If so, only the first occurrence is removed with `remove(Object)`. You could try keeping a reference to the `int` returned by `rand.nextInt` then call `remove(int)`.

Comment: @Slaw no, the list has no duplucates

Comment: Then to be of more help we require a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Slaw I can make a video to show the process and put a link to a video, is it ok?

Comment: Why do you increment the index before you remove the element. You always remove the element after the one you display from the list. Furthermore `remove` returns the element removed from the list. No need to retrieve it with a seperate `get` call: `lb_randomCard.setText(list.remove(index));` Furthermore it looks like you can avoid code duplication by storing one of the lists in a local variable inside the `if/else if` and write the code for element removal and setting the text only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you remove by index instead of removing by value.

```
private void showRandomQuestionCat2() {

  Random rand = new Random();
  int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
  String randomString = list.get(index);
  lb_randomCard.setText(randomString);
  list.remove(index);

 }
```

**Edit:**
I simulated your code with this simple example, no duplicates

```
public class test
{
    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> listSentence = new ArrayList<>();
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main (String []args)
    {
      list.add("hi1");
      list.add("hi2");
      list.add("hi3");
      list.add("hi4");
      listSentence.add("bye1");
      listSentence.add("bye2");
      listSentence.add("bye3");
      listSentence.add("bye4");

      for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        showRandomQuestionCat2();
    }

     private static void showRandomQuestionCat2() 
     {

      int n = rand.nextInt(100);
      if (n < 70) {
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        String randomString = list.get(index);
        System.out.println(list.get(index));
        list.remove(index);

      } else {
        int index2 = rand.nextInt(listSentence.size());
        String randomString = listSentence.get(index2);
        System.out.println(listSentence.get(index2));
        listSentence.remove(index2);
      }
    }
}
```

On a side note, `if (n<70)` followed by `else if (n<80)` will not given you 70%/30% chance

Comment: I've tried your answer , but same situation. It is often when strings are repated one after another.

Comment: Have you tried to shuffle the arraylist instead? Using `Collections.shuffle(arrayList);` and then iterating through the arraylist to (fake randomness)

Comment: Yes, I've tried see my edit, or may be I used Collections.shuffle in the wrong way?

Comment: I meant shuffling outside the scope and only once so you'll have a "random" list where you can set the text to the "random" list iteratively, I edited my answer with the pseudocode. Additionally, you can create a copy of that list if you still need that list but I'm assuming you do not since you're removing it.

Comment: we'll have to see more code than, currently there doesn't seem to be any issue with what we have

Comment: Thanx for your your code! I works perfectly for me. You helped me so much! but I don't get the difference between your and my code, if you know what thing has broken logic of my code it wiill be good.Thanx anyway for your help!